# Compare two strings value in rdl file

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdl, custom-code

I need to check the equality of two strings in **rdl `<code>` file.**

The below condition check only both or in Null values. but i need to check the parameter values are equal or not.

The below functions is custom function written in `<code></code>` block.
Please help.

`NPServedasperPolicy` and `NPServed` parameter values are coming from reports values.

```
   public function getNoticePeriodStatus
        (byval NPServed as String,byval NPServedasperPolicy as String)


        if(NPServedasperPolicy = NPServed)
                getNoticePeriodStatus = "Notice period Fully Served"
        end if
```

Comment: What should happen if the values are not equal?

Comment: Not Equal means set value as getNoticePeriodStatus="Notice period Not Served."

Comment: And if both are null?

Comment: Yes both are null or Not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to display:

- "Notice period Not Served" if `NPServedasperPolicy` and `NPServed` are different or both null
- "Notice period Fully Served" if `NPServedasperPolicy` and `NPServed` are equal

You could use the following custom code:

```
Public Function GetNoticePeriodStatus (ByVal NPServed as String,ByVal NPServedasperPolicy as String)
        If((Not(NPServedasperPolicy Is Nothing) And Not(NPServed Is Nothing)) and NPServedasperPolicy = NPServed) Then
                GetNoticePeriodStatus = "Notice period Fully Served"
        Else
                GetNoticePeriodStatus = "Notice period Not Served"
        End If
End Function
```

That can be called with:

```
=Code.GetNoticePeriodStatus(Parameters!NPServed.Value, Parameters!NPServedasperPolicy.Value)
```

---

For completeness, here is the plain Expression equivalent:

```
=Iif((Not(Parameters!NPServedasperPolicy.Value Is Nothing) And (Not(Parameters!NPServed.Value Is Nothing))) And Parameters!NPServedasperPolicy.Value = Parameters!NPServed.Value, "Notice period Fully Served", "Notice period Not Served")
```